# Iteration Count in "For Loop" Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, count, iteration

Write PLSQL block to display the ODD numbers and total odd numbers in given number? Ex: If given number is 3, display as below 1 is odd number 3 is odd number Total 2 odd numbers in 3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE odd_num(p_num NUMBER ) 
   IS s_num NUMBER;
BEGIN 
   FOR i_num IN 1..p_num  
      LOOP   
         IF mod(i_num,2) = 1 
         THEN     
            dbms_output.put_line(i_num ||' is Odd Number');  
         END IF; 
      END LOOP;  
   dbms_output.put_line('Total '|| s_num ||' Odd Numbers in '||p_num);
END;
```

Comment: What is the question?  It appears that you'd want to initialize `s_num` and then increment it in the `if` statement in your loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to initialize and assign the **counter** to `s_num`. Just add the following inside the **IF** block:

```
s_num := s_num +1;
```

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE odd_num(p_num NUMBER )
  2  IS
  3  s_num NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     s_num :=0;
  6     FOR i_num IN 1..p_num
  7        LOOP
  8           IF mod(i_num,2) = 1
  9           THEN
 10              -- Increment the counter once for each iteration
 11              s_num := s_num +1;
 12              dbms_output.put_line(i_num ||' is Odd Number');
 13           END IF;
 14        END LOOP;
 15     dbms_output.put_line('Total '|| s_num ||' Odd Numbers in '||p_num);
 16  END;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
```

Let's **execute** the **procedure**:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> EXEC odd_num(5);
1 is Odd Number
3 is Odd Number
5 is Odd Number
Total 3 Odd Numbers in 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I want the answer like "Total 3 odd numbers in 5".

Comment: @PrabhaChrist Welcome to Stack Overflow. I know, I updated. There was a silly typo, I added the counter inside the loop before `IF`, it should be inside IF block. Please mark it answered.